# `constexpr` constructor is not called when arguments are not known at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Currently I'm reading Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++* (*Item 15 - Use constexpr whenever possible.*). Author says:

> When a constexpr function is called with one or more values that are
>   not known during compilation, it acts like a normal function,
>   computing its result at runtime. This means you don’t need two
>   functions to perform the same operation, one for compile-time
>   constants and one for all other values. The constexpr function does it
>   all.

I've tried the following code snippet in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
    public:
        constexpr Point(double a, double b) noexcept
            : _a(a), _b(b)
        {
        }

        void print() const noexcept
        {
            std::cout << "a -> " << _a << "\tb -> " << _b << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        double _a;
        double _b;
};

double get_a() noexcept
{
    return 5.5;
}

double get_b() noexcept
{
    return 5.6;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr Point p1(2.3, 4.4);
    p1.print();
    int a = get_a();
    int b = get_b();
    constexpr Point p2(a, b);
    p2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In case of creating `p1` object all goes as expected: arguments are known compile time and members are initialized properly. In case of creating `p2` object, although we don't know the values of `a` and `b` variables at compile time, it should have worked in my understanding, because the constructor should have acted as a normal function. But I'm getting the following error messages:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()'
main.cpp:38:28: error: the value of 'a' is not usable in a constant expression
     constexpr Point p2(a, b);
                            ^
main.cpp:36:9: note: 'int a' is not const
     int a = get_a();
         ^
main.cpp:38:28: error: the value of 'b' is not usable in a constant expression
     constexpr Point p2(a, b);
                            ^
main.cpp:37:9: note: 'int b' is not const
     int b = get_b();
```

`Coliru` uses **gcc** compiler.
So, I don't understand what is the problem. Maybe I've missed something...

Comment: You shouldn't declare `p2` as `constexpr`, because it can't be. So just `Point p2(a, b);` woud be fine.

Comment: Why? In `p1` case members are initialized compile time, because we have compile time known arguments: 2.3, 4.4. In `p2` case we don't know values of `a` and `b` compile time and it doesn't mean that members should have been initialized runtime? (When a constexpr function is called with one or more values that are not known during compilation, it acts like a normal function, computing its result at runtime.)

Comment: Your quote only refers to functions. If you declare an object or expression `constexpr` you are requiring that it is evaluated at compile time, which `p2` can't be as songyuanyao pointed out.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan Yes it's evaluated at runtime, so it can't be `constexpr`, which requires to be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: OK, I've got it. I just thought that compiler will understand that constructor will be called at runtime and it will ignore `constexpr` keyword before declaration of `p2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood Scott's explanation: he did not mean that you could make `constexpr` objects with non-const data. Constructs like this are not supposed to work

```
constexpr Point p2(a, b);
```

because the compiler does not know values of `a` and `b`, so you cannot declare to the compiler that your `p2` object is `constexpr`.

What he means was that when you define a `constexpr` function or member function, like this

```
int constexpr foo(int a, int b) {
    return 2*a + b;
}
```

it would obviously work when `a` and `b` are compile-time constants, but it would continue to work even when `a` and `b` are variables:

```
cout << foo(2, 5) << endl; // This obviously works
int a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
cout << foo(a, b) << endl; // This works too
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/kiJILw)

In your case it means that you can continue calling `Point`'s constructor even with variables, but you cannot force the result into `constexpr`:

```
Point p2(a, b); // This works, even though Point(int,int) is constexpr
```

Comment: In my case `a` and `b` are not variables?

Comment: Actually the problem was that I declared `p2` as a `constexpr`.

Comment: @DavidHovsepyan Absolutely, they are. Which means that you can pass them to a `constexpr` function, but it does not mean that function result is going to be `constexpr` as well. You cannot force `constexpr` on `p2`, which is the result of `constexpr` function called with variables.

Answer (score 6):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) *(emphasis mine)*:

> A `constexpr` variable must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - its type must be a `LiteralType`.
> - it must be immediately initialized
> - **the full-expression of its initialization, including all implicit conversions, constructors calls, etc, must be a constant expression**

In your example...

```
constexpr Point p2(a, b);
```

...`a` and `b` are not constant expressions. In order to make them constant expressions, you need to mark `get_a`, `get_b`, `a`, and `b` as `constexpr`:

```
constexpr double get_a() noexcept
{
    return 5.5;
}

constexpr double get_b() noexcept
{
    return 5.6;
}
```

```
constexpr int a = get_a();
constexpr int b = get_b();
constexpr Point p2(a, b);
```